# Transfer values between 2 dataframes based on time granularity

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, datetime

I have one dataframe, `df_60` that is of 60 minute time granularity. And another with 30 minute granularity, `df_30`. I want to move the values from a column on `df_60` to a column in `df_30`, and maintain the duration of when the value appears.

So say I had a date of `2011-01-05 00:00:00 0`, an hourly granularity, and it had a value in a column `val`, of 1. How do I "fill in" the values of a 30 moinute timeframe at all times that a column in the 60 minute dataframe was equal to x ?

```
>>>df_60
dt_hr_idx           val #here val = 1 for times between 2am and 4am
2011-01-05 00:00:00 0
2011-01-05 01:00:00 0
2011-01-05 02:00:00 1
2011-01-05 03:00:00 1
2011-01-05 04:00:00 0

>>>df_30
dt_hlaf_hr_idx      val #df_30 val column is currently blank
2011-01-05 00:00:00 0
2011-01-05 00:30:00 0
2011-01-05 01:00:00 0
2011-01-05 01:30:00 0
2011-01-05 02:00:00 0
2011-01-05 02:30:00 0
2011-01-05 03:00:00 0
2011-01-05 03:30:00 0
2011-01-05 04:00:00 0

#desired df
df_30
dt_hlaf_hr_idx      val  #val should be 1 for values between 2am and 4am
2011-01-05 00:00:00 0
2011-01-05 00:30:00 0
2011-01-05 01:00:00 0
2011-01-05 01:30:00 0
2011-01-05 02:00:00 1
2011-01-05 02:30:00 1
2011-01-05 03:00:00 1
2011-01-05 03:30:00 1
2011-01-05 04:00:00 0
```

I could hack something out with loops, but is there a sane method available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with `ffill`:

```
df = df_60.reindex(df_30.index, method='ffill')
print (df)
                     val
2011-01-05 00:00:00    0
2011-01-05 00:30:00    0
2011-01-05 01:00:00    0
2011-01-05 01:30:00    0
2011-01-05 02:00:00    1
2011-01-05 02:30:00    1
2011-01-05 03:00:00    1
2011-01-05 03:30:00    1
2011-01-05 04:00:00    0
```

Another solution with [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df_30, df_60, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print (df)
                     val_x  val_y
2011-01-05 00:00:00      0      0
2011-01-05 00:30:00      0      0
2011-01-05 01:00:00      0      0
2011-01-05 01:30:00      0      0
2011-01-05 02:00:00      0      1
2011-01-05 02:30:00      0      1
2011-01-05 03:00:00      0      1
2011-01-05 03:30:00      0      1
2011-01-05 04:00:00      0      0
```

Comment: I knew I was going to kick myself over this, I really must keep myself familiar with the API. I will go with the second suggestion. Cheers for the response.